# Outlook automatic reply that retains body text of the incoming message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

I'm able to create a rule that replies to incoming emails with a template. That works as designed, however I would like for the reply to quote the original incoming email just like it would appear if I manually replied to it. At the moment the replies only have the template and nothing else.

I can't seem to figure out if this is possible - has anyone done it, and how?

Edit: More info - this is Outlook 2010 client on Windows 7. Server is Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 SP1 build 14.1.218

Comment: Lets see if the bounty hunters can be tempted by the meager rep that I can spare :)

Comment: Further clarification (prompted by Dan) - This is a rather pedestrian problem. Operating a small service desk that just needs to acknowledge incoming emails. While the existing "reply with template" does this, without the original email text, when the sender replies to the acknowledgement the context is lost, so here I'm trying to retain the content of the original email. I'm open to all suggestions, although installing something like OTRS is not an option sadly.

Answer (score 3):

The article [Copy body of email to Auto-reply in Outlook 2007](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Groupware/Outlook/Q_24699517.html) suggests the following script as solution:

```
Sub AutoReply(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olkReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olkReply = Item.Reply
    With olkReply
        'Change the subject on the next line as desired'
        .Subject = "Your Subject Goes Here"
        'Change the body as desired'
        .HTMLBody = "Your reply text goes here.<bt><br>" & olkReply.HTMLBody
        .Send
    End With
    Set olkReply = Nothing
End Sub
```

<sub>Remark: Since I posted this link, Experts Exchange has changed its business model
and has become much less accessible. The code is however duplicated above,
even if the link is unusable.</sub>

Comment: -∞ for Expertsexchange.

Comment: @harrymc: ["experts-exchange"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/introducing-stackoverflow-com.html) is ["universally loathed"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/whos-your-arch-enemy.html).

Comment: @harrymc - One issue is that your link to the reference was obfuscated with some sort of javascript garbage that blocked the answer.  Oh man I despise Expert's Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the code - I would prefer that the reply mechanism can run server-side so I don't need to keep a machine constantly running, but will keep it in mind if nothing else comes up

Comment: A reference that doesn't work is *not useful*, although the mentioned script is. +1

Comment: Using a script makes it a client-side rule, right? (i.e. only when Outlook is running)

Comment: @theglauber: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a *Reply*?  There are rule actions for both **redirect** and **forward** which might be "close enough" for your purposes.

There is also an "Out of Office" reply which might be useful.

While I realize neither of these directly answers your question, I'm trying to offer possible solutions to your problem—whatever that may be.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that I could have provided more context. Essentially yes, it does have to be a reply, or look very similar to one. I've added more detail as a comment to the question

Comment: As far as I can see, with Outlook 2013, neither Redirect nor Forward give you the option of adding additional text.  They seem to just forward the original message without the chance of including your own message as you would if you were replying.