# Is it possible to have a server side auto-reply rule on Outlook which includes the original message?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

It's easy do set up a server-side auto-reply in Outlook/Exchange with a simple, fixed email being sent back.

Is there a way to make the reply dynamic, specifically, to quote the original message in the auto-reply?

(https://superuser.com/a/260772/111443 has a client-side solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid not.

When you go to OWA (Outlook Web Access) and go to `Set Automatic replies`, your options are limited.

The automatic reply whether internal or external source will just have the message you type in the response body.

If you have access to the Exchange Server or a willing accomplice, you can set up an [Exchange server side script](http://www.cdolive.com/autoreply.htm).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for also providing the server-side script; looks like a good script, and if it comes to that, it will probably do what i need.